# Unable to write full pivot table to a new sheet in an existing excel workbook using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to write the pivot table generated a new sheet in an existing workbook, but when I open the excel file I dont see the indexes, I see only values. However I can see the complete pivot correctly in terminal.

I created this file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx')
```

I have this in a sheet in the above file created:

```
lookup = pd.merge(ns,sfdc[['Account ID','Account Status']],on=['Account ID'],how='left')

lookup.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='latest_sg',index=False)
```

I did a pivot table:

```
pivot = lookup.pivot_table(index=['Account ID','accountname'],values=['gb'],aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)

pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='pivot', index=False)
writer.save()
```

in terminal I get the output for :

```
print(pivot)

                                              gb
Account ID   accountname                     
1-1          ABC Inc.                         0
1-2          DEF                              1
1-3          XYZ                            974
1-4          TRX                             00
```

But in the Output.xlsx I get a new sheet as 'pivot that gets created but the sheet has only GB column:

```
gb
0
1
974
00
```

The excel sheet does not show complete pivot table details.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem  `MultiIndex` is removed in `to_excel`, because `index=False` parameter.

Correct solution is remove `index=False`, but then possible empty row after header:

```
pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='pivot')
```

Or convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then not write default `Rangeindex` with `index=False`:

```
pivot.reset_index().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='pivot', index=False)
```